# Unity C# - Physics.Raycast method with a LayerMask doesn't seem to ignore given layers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Hello i'm using a layer mask while ray casting but whatever i do it doesn't ignore the given layer.
I used this method before & was working fine. Guess there is a problem that a i cannot resolve.
Here is how i use the method:

```
    // Ignore layers 21 & 0
    int layerMask = ~LayerMask.GetMask(LayerMask.LayerToName(21), LayerMask.LayerToName(0));
    if (Physics.Raycast(position, direction, out hit, maxDistance, layerMask)) {
        // Always reaching this point where hit.transform.gameObject.layer = 21
        if (XLayers.shouldDoStuff(hit.transform.gameObject.layer)) {
          // DO stuff
       } else{ // other stuff }
    } else { some other stuff }
```

I know there 16 overloads of this method but i'm sure mine is the correct one.

As far as i know this symbol ( ~ ) makes it ignore the given layers. I tried to remove it too the result is the same.

Also i tried to send 0 as the layer mask which means ignore all layers, i this case the ray collides with nothing as expected
.
Any advice appreciated thanks.

Comment: I think you are doing the opposite - you are passing the layers to hit not to ignore?

Comment: I was pretty sure the symbol ~ means ignore but I tried remove it too. Still the result is the same, which is weird.

Comment: You are right, it should reverse the bitmap. Not sure what is going on. I would make the layer public and check it in the inspector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.
This is my prefab:

```
ParentGameObject ( Layer : 21, has rigidBody, has collider )
    ChildGameObject ( Layer : 18, no ridigBody, has collider )
```

The parent layer is ignored as it should be & the child is collided with the ray.

**BUT** hit.transform.gameObject.layer **returns you the layer** of the **gameObject that CONTAINS THE RIGIDBODY**. Which is the ParentGameObject. Doesn't matter what layer is the game object contaning the collider.

For the solution I added a rigidbody to the ChildGameObject it works now.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to understand and deal with layer masks if you abstract it.

As an example, if you want to get a mask for specific layers:

```
LayerMask mask = LayerUtility.Only("Player", "Friends");
```

Or if you want to exclude specific layers:

```
LayerMask mask = LayerUtility.AllBut("Enemies", "Obstacles");
```

Here is the main utility class:

```
public static class LayerUtility
{
    public static LayerMask Only(params string[] ids)
    {
        LayerMask mask = new LayerMask();

        for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
        {
            mask = Add(mask, Shift(Get(ids[i])));
        }

        return mask;
    }

    public static LayerMask AllBut(params string[] ids)
    {
        return Invert(Only(ids));
    }

    public static LayerMask Invert(LayerMask mask)
    {
        return ~mask;
    }

    public static LayerMask Add(LayerMask mask1, LayerMask mask2)
    {
        return mask1 | mask2;
    }

    public static LayerMask Shift(LayerMask mask)
    {
        return 1 << mask;
    }

    public static LayerMask Get(string id)
    {
        return LayerMask.NameToLayer(id);
    }
}
```